# Render Twig templates in Controller - Slim 4 Framework

Tags: php, twig, slim

Like said in the title, I looking to rendering twig template in controller using Slim 4 framework.

I searched on the Internet, but I didn't find a solution that works for me and well-explained.

If someone can explains me how can I make this to work.

Here the code a my files:

index.php

```
<?php
use App\Controllers\HomeController;
use DI\Container;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

### Container ###
$container = new Container();

### Slim ###
AppFactory::setContainer($container);
$app = AppFactory::create();

### Twig ###
$container = $app->getContainer();
$container['view'] = function ($c) {
    return $c;
};
$container['HomeController'] = function ($c) {
    return new HomeController($c['view']);
};

### Routes ###
$app->get('/',HomeController::class . ":home");
$app->get('/home', HomeController::class . ":home");

### Run ###
$app->run();
```

HomeController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Slim\Psr7\Request;
use Slim\Psr7\Response;

class HomeController
{
    private $app;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $app)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
    }

    public function home(Request $request, Response $response)
    {
        $this->app->get('view')->render($response, 'home.twig');
    }
}
```

composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "4.*",
        "slim/psr7": "^1.0",
        "slim/twig-view": "^3.0",
        "php-di/php-di": "^6.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    }
}
```

project structure

[image]

And when I start the server, the console gives me:

```
PHP 7.3.11-0ubuntu0.19.10.2 Development Server started at Tue Feb 18 16:33:41 2020
Listening on http://localhost:8080
Document root is /home/thomas/Code/2020/S4/prog_web/homelogin/public
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
[Tue Feb 18 16:33:44 2020] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type DI\Container as array in /home/thomas/Code/2020/S4/prog_web/homelogin/public/index.php:17
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/thomas/Code/2020/S4/prog_web/homelogin/public/index.php on line 17
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to add twig-view in slimframework v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57471005/how-to-add-twig-view-in-slimframework-v4)

Comment: What's the exact problem? I don't think that the given error message has any connection to Twig

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use **DI\Container** object as an array. You should use [`set()`](http://php-di.org/doc/container.html#set) method to add a service to the container instead.

Replace these lines:

```
$container['view'] = function ($c) {
    return $c;
};
$container['HomeController'] = function ($c) {
    return new HomeController($c['view']);
};
```

with these:

```
$container->set('view', function () {
    return \Slim\Views\Twig::create('../resources/views', ['cache' => false]);
});
$container->set('HomeController', function () use ($container) {
    return new HomeController($container);
});
```

And then you should return a response (*ResponseInterface*) in the **home()** method of your **HomeController** class:

```
public function home(Request $request, Response $response)
{
    return $this->app->get('view')->render($response, 'templates/home.twig');
}
```

Note that your `home.twig` file is located in the **templates** directory.

Read more about [Dependency Container](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/concepts/di.html) and [Twig](https://github.com/slimphp/Twig-View) in Slim.

Comment: Thank for your help but now php gives me this : ` PHP Fatal error:  Class DI\Container contains 3 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods`. Any ideas why?

Comment: The structure of your project is pretty similar to mine. Here is a [Github repo](https://github.com/nbayramberdiyev/slim-4-starter). Hope this helps.